# Not able to connect to XPCService in a Launch agent

Tags: macos, xpc, nsxpcconnection

I have created an XPC Service .

the server side code briefly is

```
NSXPCListener *listener = [[NSXPCListener alloc] initWithMachServiceName:@"test.xpcserver"];
listener.delegate = delegate;
 [listener resume];
```

this is installed as a Launch Agent using info.plist as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>TestServer</string>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>test.xpcserver</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/test.app/Contents/XPCServices/xpcserver.xpc/Contents/MacOS/xpcserver</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The server is running fine and i can see it running with **launchctl list**

The client side code is in another app and the code for connect is:

```
connection = [[NSXPCConnection alloc] initWithMachServiceName:@“test.xpcserver” options:0];       
  connection.remoteObjectInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:@protocol(xpcserverprotocol)]; 
[connection resume]; 
  service = [connection remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) { }];
   [service ServerFunc:@“howdy” withReply:^(NSString *result) {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }];
```

but not able to connect to server .
any pointers as to what going wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

(Posting this for future readers, I imagine OP solved their problem by now :) )

Some other things to check:

1. Make sure your launch agent/deamon is using the [`-[NSXPCListener initWithMachServiceName]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpclistener/1414106-initwithmachservicename?language=objc), and not [`+[NSXPCListener serviceListener]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpclistener/1408414-servicelistener?language=objc).

   - The latter is only useful for regular XPC service (which would be stored in the App's bundle, not in `/Library/...`.  If you mix it up, you'll get a crash report in Console.app that will say:

     > Configuration error: Couldn't retrieve XPCService dictionary from service bundle.
2. In your agent/daemon, don't forget to start the main run loop after `[listener resume];` with `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];`
3. In your agent/daemon, make sure there's a strong reference to keep your listener's `delegate` alive. The [`-[NSXPCListener delegate]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpclistener/1408939-delegate?language=objc) property is declared `weak`, so it's possible that your listener deallocates immediately after you set it. I would put an `NSLog` statement in the `deinit` of your delegate's class, just to be sure.

Comment: my man! the issue for me was the not having a strong reference to my delegate! thank you!

Comment: Thank you, it's super not obvious that listener resume will NOT block for LaunchAgent while it does for the app service.

Comment: @dev_null Glad this helped, even 3 years after writing :)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from what you've posted.  Things to check:

- ensure your listener delegate is implementing right function signature for `shouldAcceptNewConnection()`.  If it's not right, you will not get any error.  It should be

`- (BOOL)listener:(NSXPCListener *)listener shouldAcceptNewConnection:(NSXPCConnection *)conn { your code here }`

- Use System Logging (NSLog) or add logging of stdout and stderr for your service.  See the `launch.sh` in this [hello_world_xpc example](https://github.com/wuntee/hello_world_xpc/), which generates the plist based on local paths.  That example is using the C API, so not exactly what you are looking for.
- See old Objective-C hello.tar.gz example here : [afewguyscoding.com/2012/07/ipc-easy-introducing-xpc-nsxpcconnection/](http://afewguyscoding.com/2012/07/ipc-easy-introducing-xpc-nsxpcconnection/)